# Can i use a custom list to Connect to Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, outlook

I know I can use a contact list and this would connect to outlook.
But I have a custom list and I would like to let it connect to outlook.
Is there a way I can convert this list?
Thanks in Advance
Cheers